# Cross platform screen sharing with Temasys

Tags: android, webrtc, skylink

I am trying to share screen from android to web. Following the tutorial provided, I am able to share screen from two different PC's on web. On android I followed same steps to stream from mobile screen but when I try to connect android to web it dose not stream.

I used logs to check debug the problem
For Web:

```
///////////////////////////// Peer Joined //////////////////////////////
peerId      ::  7ebfmEsB3BMX7xTgF8DI
peerInfo    ::  Object {userData: "", settings: Object, mediaStatus: Object, agent: Object, room: "SkylinkShare"…}
isSelf      ::  true
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// Media Access Success ////////////////////////////
 stream     ::  MediaStream {id: "0B06WpGwnTV9fw98TrlFJVp8p3Bs3Fk8FLPq", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// Incoming Stream ////////////////////////////////
peerId      ::  7ebfmEsB3BMX7xTgF8DI
stream      ::  MediaStream {id: "0B06WpGwnTV9fw98TrlFJVp8p3Bs3Fk8FLPq", active: true, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null, onactive: null}
isSelf      ::  true
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

For Android:
Peer connects but Media Access and incoming stream functions do not get trigger

```
///////////////////////////// Peer Joined //////////////////////////////
peerId      ::  hZbjN--0lrjBsjbWF8Mn
peerInfo    ::  Object {settings: Object, mediaStatus: Object, userData: "9bf62f0b7d7387d1", config: Object, parentId: null…}
isSelf      ::  false
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: I don't believe screensharing is implemented in mobile browsers, if that's what you mean.

Comment: @jib no its on native android app. Dose it need to be in browser ?

Comment: Dunno much about android native, sorry. Do you have reason to believe it is implemented?